# LDAP authentication from spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, ldap, roles

I am trying to set in java config ldap authorization with roles from my db. My setup is

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity( prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true )
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
.
.
.
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsContextMapper userDetailsContextMapper() {
        return new UserDetailsContextMapper() {
            @Override
            public UserDetails mapUserFromContext(
                    DirContextOperations ctx, String username,
                    Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
                String lowercaseLogonName = username.toLowerCase();
                Optional<PtolUser> userFromDatabase =
                        ptolUserRepository.findOneByLogonName(lowercaseLogonName);
                return userFromDatabase.map(user ->
                    {
                        if (!user.isAccountNonExpired()) {
                            throw new UserNotActivatedException(
                                    "User " + lowercaseLogonName + " was not activated");
                        }
                        List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = user.getUserAuthorities().parallelStream()
                                .map(authority -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(authority.getRole().getName()))
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
                        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(lowercaseLogonName,
                                user.getPassword(), true, user.isAccountNonExpired(), true,
                                user.isAccountNonLocked(), grantedAuthorities);
                    }).orElseThrow(
                            () -> new UsernameNotFoundException(
                                    "User " + lowercaseLogonName + " was not found in the AD"));
            }

            @Override
            public void mapUserToContext(UserDetails user, DirContextAdapter ctx) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Only retrieving data from LDAP is currently supported");
            }

        };
    }
.
.
.
    @Bean
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {       
        auth//
                .ldapAuthentication()//
                // .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)//
                .userDetailsContextMapper(userDetailsContextMapper())//
                .userDnPatterns(env.getRequiredProperty("ldap.user_dn_patterns"))//
                .groupSearchBase(env.getRequiredProperty("ldap.group_search_base"))//
                .groupSearchFilter(env.getRequiredProperty("ldap.group_search_filter"))//
                .contextSource()//
                .ldif("ptolemaios.ldif");
    }
.
.
.
}
```

but i have the following warning/error (2 times)

> Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling
>   refresh attempt:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'configureGlobal' defined in class path
>   resource [com/ppc/ptol2/config/SecurityConfiguration.class]: Invalid
>   factory method 'configureGlobal': needs to have a non-void return
>   type!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `@Bean` annotation from your `public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)` method *(and add an `@Override` annotation instead)*